# To the best or To best?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

Which one is correct:

- Happy 50th anniversary **to** **the** world's best grandparents

or

- Happy 50th anniversary **to** world's best grandparents

Comment: Prefer the first. They are the best grandparents in **the** world.

Comment: "to the World's Best Grandparents"

Answer (score 1):

The definite article "the" is needed here. When using superlatives, "the" is natually used, since the superlative identifies a single example

- The fastest car is the Bugatti
- Maths is the most interesting subject
- To the best grandparents in the world
- To the world's best grandparents.